# Applying Extrude Expressions to Multiple Layers/Shapefiles in Arcscene? Python script

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, 3d-analyst, arcscene, extrude

I have 100 shapefiles of cities with census tracts that I need to be extruded to certain values. I already have the shapefiles set up the way they need to be and would like to avoid manually opening every file to set the extrude expression. Can I use python to do this? I don't mind running 100 lines of script (1 for each file), but I can't seem to figure out how to do that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use arcpy to work with ArcScene and sxd layers.

You will be able to manage extrusion and other properties of 3D layers with the new mapping module in [ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/) - check the [Layer properties and methods](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) available in ArcGIS Pro.

You can try the prerelease of ArcGIS Pro right now if you have a current maintenance contract with Esri, I advise you to do so if you work frequently with 3D data. The official release is foreseen January 2015.

Otherwise, if your shapefiles all have the extrusion property based on the same field (and if they have the same symbology), you could merge them altogether and set the extrusion only once?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was going to merge the files all together, but the problem is I need the symbology/ranges to be based on the values within each city. So unless I can merge them and then still use quartile for the values within each city....